# What happens when a PAT expires

Tags: azure-devops

In azure devops when you create a PAT you can set it's lifetime up to a year.  What happens when it expires?  Does it auto renew?  Do I need to crate a new one and for every service that uses it, I need to track down and update it's credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I had expirienced the same problem, I needed to renew manually my PAT.

[VS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/318764/no-ability-to-renew-one-of-your-personal-access-to.html)

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/431f9a06-db69-49d4-8bc0-3bff9911f959/vsts-private-agent-authentication-with-pat-personal-access-tokens?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-bBl9hy5b6hOJq0sTuMsSjA&epi=TnL5HPStwNw-bBl9hy5b6hOJq0sTuMsSjA&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__ycnzsugzpttxs6zupjtyxx1ox22xhsa9agaxcn2h00)(7593)(1243925)(TnL5HPStwNw-bBl9hy5b6hOJq0sTuMsSjA)()&irclickid=_ycnzsugzpttxs6zupjtyxx1ox22xhsa9agaxcn2h00)

Comment: Did you have to update it on every server/service that used it to authenticate?

Comment: Not in my case, we have a central \ common webapi that we use, and was changed there, in azdevops, we use a common library with all tokens and credentials and it was easy to change.
We face the same problem in package management from VS with npm tokens